# pushgateway or node exporter - how to add string data?

Tags: sql, cron, prometheus

I have a cron job that runs an sql query every day, and gives me an important integer.

And I have to expose that integer to the Prometheus server.

As I've seen I have two options; use the **pushgateway** or **node exporter**.

But that metric (integer) that I get from the sql query also need some information (like the company name, and the database that I got it from).

What would be a better way?

For instance this is what I made for my metric:

```
    count = some number

    registry = CollectorRegistry()
    g = Gauge('machine_number', 'machfoobarine_stat', registry=registry).set(count)
    push_to_gateway('localhost:9091', job='batchA', registry=registry)
```

So how do I add key-value pairs to my metric above? 
Do I have to change the job name ('batchA') for every single sql count that I get and expose as a metric to the pushgateway, because I can only see the last one?

Tnx,
Tom

Comment: Are you asking us how to query the extra fields you need to be picked up on or how to configure the fields to be exported?

Comment: I'm asking how to configure the fields! Basically I want to find out how to set the labels for the metric (integer) for the pushdgateway, or how to integrate that additional data with the metric that I'm exposing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to set a general name to your metric, for example animal_count and then specialize it with label. Here is an pseudocode:

```
g = Gauge.build("animal_count", "Number of animal in zoo")
    .labelsName("sex", "classes")
    .create();

g.labels("male", "mammals")
    .set(count);
```